# hadoop master host fails to connect to localhost: connection refused

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hdfs, centos7, firewall

I've setup HDFS with two nodes, on different hosts, in the same network. I'm using HDFS C++ API. Hdfs name node and data nodes start normally, but when I try to read any data, or open a file, I get the following error:

```
Call From master/192.168.X.X to localhost:54310 failed on connection exception: connection refused
```

So I guess it's connected with ssh.

On master box, the following commands work (/etc/hosts file contains master and slave):

```
ssh master
ssh slave
ssh localhost
ssh user@localhsot
ssh localhost -p 22
```

But when I try `ssh localhost -p 54310`, it fails with 'connection refused' error. But ps -ef | grep :54310shows that name node listens on that port.

Any ideas how to fix that?

**hdfs-site.xml**

```
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>2</value>
    <description>Default block replication.
    The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
    The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
    </description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.max.locked.memory</name>
    <value>0</value>
    <description>Default block replication.
    The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
    The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
    </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**mapreg-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>master:54311</value>
    <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
    at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
    and reduce task.
    </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**core-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<property>
    <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
    <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
    <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://master:54310</value>
    <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
    scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
    uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
    the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
    determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

**slaves**

```
master
slave
```

**masters**

```
master
```

EDIT: results from netstat -an

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54310         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54310         127.0.0.1:45156         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45156         127.0.0.1:54310         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54310         127.0.0.1:45140         TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:54310         127.0.0.1:45134         TIME_WAIT
```

I've also replaced master with localhost on master host, which solved the problem on master. Now the only error I'm getting is in slave, which fails to connect to the master

```
2018-01-21 23:53:18,597 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/    192.168.0.237:54310. Already tried 8 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSl    eep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-01-21 23:53:19,599 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/    192.168.0.237:54310. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSl    eep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-01-21 23:53:19,609 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Problem connecti    ng to server: master/192.168.0.237:54310
2018-01-21 23:53:25,613 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/    192.168.0.237:54310. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSl    eep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
2018-01-21 23:53:26,615 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: master/    192.168.0.237:54310. Already tried 1 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSl    eep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
```

Comment: I've never seen port 44444 used before in hadoop. It's definitely not an SSH port. The namenode and datanode connect over RPC

Comment: 1) Did you add `master` to `/etc/hosts` on all machines? 2) Stop using `localhost` in your configurations, replace it with the `192.168.x.x` address of that server

Comment: I'm configuring hadoop, can't I use any port I wish? 1. ssh master works as you can see, so yes, I've added it. 2. my configurations have master/slave instead of ip's, I have no idea why it tries to connect to localhost

Comment: log files don't have any errors

Comment: I would suggest that you stick to the default ports unless there's already a previous conflict. Do you ensure your hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml files are copied over all machines?

Comment: I haven't copied, but I changed in the same way. I'm using 54310 and 54311 ports now, still the same.

Comment: Which values are you changing? Can you add the xml files to the question?

Comment: Added config files. By the way, I'm starting only hdfs.

Comment: What are you reading to set these? `fs default.name` is deprecated and if you only want to start HDFS, mapred-site is not used, but `mapred.job.tracker` isn't a configuration I can see in the stable Hadoop 2.7 configurations https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml

Comment: Yes I'm using old doc for configuration, but single node version worked ideally. and I've changed those single nodes into slave/master.

Comment: Alright, well I might suggest using IP addresses instead of names, turning off all firewalls, then using telnet to check all ports.

Comment: Could you run `netstat -an` and [edit] your question to include the line for this port 54310?

Comment: added result to the question.